# How to install ubuntu without any extra packages that are currently installed by default?

Tags: 11.10, installation

I'm just looking to install Ubuntu 11.10 + DE (Unity and it's dependencies). All the other extra packages such as firefox/thunderbird/video player/etc and any other package that is not a dependency of a core package I don't want to install.

Comment: It was Ubuntu Mini actually not server...my bad

Comment: You have two options `command line install` of ubuntu alternate iso which lets you choose package for installation or `minimalcd` I guess.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score -2):

What you want to do does not make much sense. Ubuntu is generated from a debian fork and aimed to became a desktop friendly distribution with a specific behaviour, Ubuntu is also a brand and the latest trand is pushing this way much more than ever.
Technically speaking, in my experience, removing packages from a standard Ubuntu installation can only generate problems, Ubuntu it's not designed to be "modular", it's simply not its goal.

I suggest to do a basic installation of a Debian and install Unity from the source.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense. I don't use many of the packages installed by default hence I don't want them in the first place but I do like Ubuntu, and I do want to have the choice of what software to be install. How does this make it a less desktop friendly distribution ?

Comment: I do not use many of the utility included with Windows 7 but i must install them anyway everytime i want to setup a pc with my copy of Windows. What doesn't make sense is not about your needs, it's what you want to do.

Comment: Ok.. Ubuntu mini ISO does what you want!.. it's only the Ubuntu core nothing more nothing less, then you can proceed and install whatever you want.

Comment: @Micro what does Windows 7 have to do with our discussion ?

Comment: it's an example ...

Comment: @micro, I think you haven't infact read the question properly, or you don't care to understand it. either way, your answer is not at all helpful